# Opening app from email link in NativeScript vue iOS

Tags: nativescript, deep-linking, applinks, nativescript-vue

*Edit* For more explanation on how to use this plugin with vue, please see [NativeScript vue, vuex and urlhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365775/nativescript-vue-vuex-and-urlhandler)

---

I'm trying to make it so that a link in an email can open an app I'm building (its a test app I'm building to learn NativeScript). I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-urlhandler with NativeScript vue on iOS.

In `platforms/ios/######/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist` I have added

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>com.#######.######</string>
   </dict>
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
           <string>mycustomappfoobar</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

And within app.js, I have added:

```
const handleOpenURL = require("nativescript-urlhandler").handleOpenURL;


handleOpenURL(function(appURL) {
    console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
  });
```

When tapping on `mycustomappfoobar://test` (link in email) nothing happens...

I looked at the Angular example, and handleOpenURL is being called on initialisation... So I tried putting handleOpenURL within vues mounted hook - but this doesn't work either. Really stumped...

```
new Vue({
    mounted() {
      handleOpenURL(function(appURL) {
        console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);
      });
    },
    render: h => h("frame", [h(Home)]),
    store: Store
}).$start();
```

Comment: The plugin has nothing to do with opening the app upon clicking the link. It's done by the OS by identifying the url schemes (CFBundleURLSchemes) you listed at build time.  The plugin is only responsible for capturing the URL & parameters used to open the app. Try a clean build, make sure your CFBundleURLSchemes changes are included.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj - I've tried a clean build (however, it seems to knock out / overwrite the schemes I've put into info.plist).

Comment: Oops, just noticed you are updating wrong info plist, that's auto generated one, basically anything inside platforms folder. Use the one within your `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist`.

Comment: Thanks - I shall go and try this now :)

Comment: AMAZING! - I get one error message, "Merging CFBundleURLTypes: Property CFBundleTypeRole is required!" - but it all works... thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating wrong `info.plist`. Basically anything inside platforms folder is auto generated. Use the one within your `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `handleOpenURL` too late. This should be called prior to your `Vue` context being created so that the `UIAppDelegate` can be properly augmented behind the scenes.

<sup>*From [https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler/blob/cd6939119910b6345e444055ad17716a7c0ad1d6/demo/app/app.ts](https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler/blob/cd6939119910b6345e444055ad17716a7c0ad1d6/demo/app/app.ts_)*</sup>

```js
import { handleOpenURL, AppURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

import './app.scss';
import './bundle-config';
import * as app from 'application';

handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {
    console.log('handleOpenURL', appURL);
});

app.start({ moduleName: 'main-page' });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian MacDonald. Is this example typescript? (just the way the argument is called on handleOpenURL?). I've been calling it ahead of vue... but tried it within vue's mounted hook while I was trying to figure out why it wasn't working for me... it turns out it wasn't working because I was being dumb by putting my config in the wrong file...

Comment: Edit - in vue, you need to call handlOpenURL from within mounted, else you won't have access to all the methods.... Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365775/nativescript-vue-vuex-and-urlhandler