# NativeScript vue, vuex and urlhandler

Tags: nativescript, vuex, deep-linking, nativescript-vue

*Edit*

I'm using https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler to open a deep link within my app - using NativeScript vue, and vuex. It seems that in order to get at the methods needed to do routing [`$navigateTo` etc] this plugin needs to be set up slightly differently from the examples given in docs.

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

import { handleOpenURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

new Vue({
    mounted() {
        handleOpenURL( (appURL) => {
            console.log(appURL)
            // Settings is the variable that equals the component - in this case settings.
            this.$navigateTo(Settings);
        });
    },
    render: h => h("frame", [h(Home)]),
    store: ccStore
}).$start();
```

handleOpenURL needs to be called within Mounted - then you can parse out the appURL and reference the page (component) that you wish to navigate to. I have been advised against calling handleOpenURL from within router - but I'm not sure why, and it works without error - and I have access to the methods for routing... so if anyone knows if this is a bad idea - please let me know :) Thanks!

All the stuff below that I wrote before has probably confused things - I'm referencing components within my vuex store to make them easily available from the router.

This is based on a solution by https://github.com/Spacarar - it can be found here: https://github.com/geodav-tech/vue-nativescript-router-example. It's a great solution because you don't have to include every single component within each component to use in navigation - it gives an almost vue router like experience.

---

I'm using https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler to open a deep link within my app - however, I'm having problems opening the link.

In my app.js file, I have the following:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);
....
import { handleOpenURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';
import ccStore  from './store/store';


handleOpenURL(function(appURL) {
// I have hardwired 'Settings' in for testing purposes - but this would be the appURL
    ccStore.dispatch('openAppURL', 'Settings');
});

....

new Vue({
    render: h => h("frame", [h(Home)]),
    store: ccStore
}).$start();
```

I'm storing the route state within vuex, and have various methods which work (clicking on a link loads the component). However, handleOpenURL exists outside of vue... so I've had to access vuex directly from within the handleOpenURL method. I've created an action specifically for this case - openAppURL.. it does exactly the same thing as my other methods (although I've consolidated it).

When clicking on an app link, I am NOT taken to the page within the app. I have put a console log within openAppURL and can see it is being called, and the correct route object is returned... it just doesn't open the page. The SetTimeOut is used because nextTick isn't available from within vuex.

I am at a loss on how to get the page to appear...

```
const ccStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {
            authToken: null,
            refreshToken: null,
        },
        routes: [
            {
                name: "Home",
                component: Home
            },
            {
                name: "Log In",
                component: Login
            },
            ...
        ],
        currentRoute: {
            //INITIALIZE THIS WITH YOUR HOME PAGE
            name: "Home",
            component: Home //COMPONENT
        },
        history: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        navigateTo(state, newRoute, options) {
            state.history.push({
                route: newRoute,
                options
            });
       },
    },
    actions: {
        openAppURL({state, commit}, routeName ) {
            const URL =  state.routes[state.routes.map( (route) => {
                return route.name;
            }).indexOf(routeName)];

            return setTimeout(() => {
                commit('navigateTo', URL, { animated: false, clearHistory: true });
        }, 10000);
       },
       ....
     }
   etc....
```

Comment: Are you using Vue Router, I hope you are aware it's not supported. I neither see any code related to manual routing above, can you please explain where exactly you are running the navigation code.

Comment: Hi @Manoj - I am doing the route bit within a mixin - but you're absolutely right, I had to refactor in order to get at the $navigateTo Method... I shall update the above with my revised code... It seems that NativeScript vue needs to be set up differently to the examples in https://github.com/hypery2k/nativescript-urlhandler. I'd appreciate it if you could give your opinion on it - will post now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been advised to post my findings as the answer and mark it as correct. In order to use nativescript-urlhandler with vue, you must initialise the handler from within vue's mounted life cycle hook. Please see above for greater detail.

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

import Settings from "~/components/Settings";

import { handleOpenURL } from 'nativescript-urlhandler';

new Vue({
    mounted() {
        handleOpenURL( (appURL) => {
            console.log(appURL) // here you can get your appURL path etc and map it to a component... eg path === 'Settings. In this example I've just hardwired it in.
            this.$navigateTo(Settings);
        });
    },
    render: h => h("frame", [h(Home)]),
    store: ccStore
}).$start();
```